# Netsuite search filter conditions not working

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm doing a Netsuite search but the filters do not actually do any filtering?  The "budgetimport" object has 314 items in it, and no matter how I attempt to filter the search, all 314 items are returned every time.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Whilst I'm here: what's the "best" way to get the value in the 'amount' column from the search?  (There should only be one item returned from the search, but what if there are more?)

```
//add search columns
var columns = [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('year'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('department'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('account'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('amount'));

//add search filters
var filters = [];
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('year', null, 'anyof', 'FY 2007', null));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('department', null, 'anyof', 'Bass', null));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', 'Administration Expenses', null));

//execute the search
var search = nlapiSearchRecord('budgetimport', null, filters, columns);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing and much frustration, the problem lies with the "non-standard" object in NetSuite, so "normal" methods of doing things don't apply.

To filter on the budgetimport object, you need to use "formulatext" and set you filter on that, e.g.

```
//add search filters
var filters = [];
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('formulatext', null, 'is', fiscalyear).setFormula('{Year}')); //NOTE : Capital 'Y' in Year
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('formulatext', null, 'is', costcentre).setFormula('{department}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pairing `anyof` operator with the internal ids instead.

Example:

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('year', null, 'anyof', *internal id of 'FY 2007'*, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with that record type.  I could not find anything about it in the records browser, so I'm not sure what the allowed filters are.  The issue is that those fields are not filtering.  If you add in a filter for internalid and enter the internaid of one of the records, it will filter (see below).  I would suggest submitting a case with NetSuite about this, as it appears to be a defect with this record.?

```
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid',null,'is','12345'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, W3bguy.

I have spent a little more time working on the problem and MAY have a sort-of-work-around which MIGHT work... ?  *crosses fingers*

I have sent a message to Netsuite asking why 'internalid' works in a filter condition, but it seems that nothing else does?!  I am waiting to receive a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this recordtype gets full scripting/savedsearch support in NetSuite.

I added the following lines to your script in the NetSuite debugger to save the savedsearch.  This part worked however errors when I try to edit it.  Most likely not a fully supported recordtype.

```
//var search = nlapiSearchRecord('budgetimport', null, filters, columns);
var search = nlapiCreateSearch( 'budgetimport', filters, columns );
var searchId = search.saveSearch('BudgetImport_SEARCH', 'customsearch_budgetimport_search');
```

Keep us updated if NetSuite give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your filters don't work could be of the ff reasons:

- you're using text as filter values instead of internal id's
- you are not passing array when you're using anyof operator
- also, there is no need to pass null as last param

Answer (score 0):

Don't see this mentioned here, but I ran into this issue when I was working on one of my scripts the other day:

```
//add search filters
var filters = [];
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('year', null, 'anyof', 'FY 2007', null));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('department', null, 'anyof', 'Bass', null));
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', 'Administration Expenses', null));
```

If all of these fields are select fields sourced from lists (custom or not), then you need to be **referencing the field value by Internal Id** (I say "need" as that is what I had to do in order to filter properly with pricing).

So instead of using "FY 2007", find its internal id in the context of its parent list.

To find the internal id of the value you are trying to filter by, you can create a saved search that lists the value along with it's internal id, this can be done from any parent record of the select field. (This is a method that I had to use in order to find the internal id of price levels, as I could not find that anywhere else in our system).

If it's a custom list, navigate to your custom lists page, find the list, and identify the internal id for the value you are trying to filter by.